# what is the equivalent of Lathander from the Dawn War Deities

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities

A player getting his cleric ready for a campaign I am creating has told me he usually plays Forgotten Realms and his usual deity is Lathander, this is not a deity I am familiar with.

Largely I am basing my Pantheon for this campaign on the DawnWar Deities, with some tweaks being made. I am perfectly happy allowing my Cleric to play Lathander, and he is equally happy to worship an equivalent deity in my pantheon.

Who would be the closest equivalent to Lathander from the Dawn War Deities, either to be replaced by Lathander or to replace him as my players Deity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no direct equivalent but Pelor is probably the closest match

According to the Fifth Edition PHB (page 294), Lathander is the neutral good god of birth and renewal and is associated with the life and light domains. His symbols is a sun.

In the 4th Edition PHB (page 22), the closest to this would probably be Pelor who is the good god of sun and summer (his symbol is also a sun) and is the lord of agriculture/harvest*.

One might be able to connect the dots between Pelor's farming and harvesting, which deal with the cycle of the seasons, and Lathander's theme of renewal.

---

<sup>User Someone_Evil♦ points out that Pelor is listed as a neutral good god in 5e and is associated with life and light just like Lathander. I guess Pelor must have seen an opportunity to expand his market appeal...</sup>

Comment: The 5e DMG puts Pelor as NG with the life and light domains FWIW.

Comment: @som Ah, yes. Gotta love those fluid deity traits. Thanks for pointing that out!